# Reducing docker image size

Tags: docker, docker-image

I downloaded an image that has only debian OS inside and started to build on it. The debian image was about 700mb when I first started with it. After installing LAMP, drupal site, varnish, tomcat, solr and some other services. The image has gone up significantly (i,e) upto 13 gb and after importing a 3gb mysql dump to that image the size of the image doubled to about 29gb.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to reduce the overall size of the image?

Comment: Read the best practices for Dockerfiles: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ Ideally, each service is contained in their own container (Apache, MySQL, PHP-FPM, ...). Splitting everything up and being smart about the layers of your Docker image(s) should give you the best result. And don't use Docker like a virtual machine.

Comment: Another thing that you could try out is a more minimal base image like alpine. It was built with compactness in mind, so it makes a good fit for containers when you're concerned about the size of the final image. You don't necessarily need to use it for all your services, but it could be a good fit for several of them.

Answer (score 0):

One small trick is to use `apt-get install` with the [`--no-install-recommends`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65081/what-are-the-implications-of-no-install-recommends-apt-get-install) flag passed. This will install the minimum dependencies for the packages you are installing.

That being said, putting everything in a Dockerfile is an antipattern. Each "application" should be it's own Docker container. So you'd have one for Varnish, one for Solr, one for the database, one for the drupal site etc. Each will be relatively small by comparison. They'll all share the base debian image as well. To coordinate them, use something like [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).